# Use calculated fields in a Google Sheets pivot table to count rows where a field equals a specific value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sample sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Of8JhSnFziFcxSqb4C4eRnZnob1ZuxAnqQOCGdzqvqI/copy.

I have a sheet/tab with data: `Sheet1`.

I have created a pivot table: `Pivot Table 1`.

In my pivot table I can count how many rows there are for each row groupingg.

What I am now trying to do is count how many rows are for a row grouping where a column value equals something.

Using my data as an example, I want my pivot table to have these columns:

- number of rows where `Col 1` is equal to `Type 1`
- number of rows where `Col 1` is equal to `Type 1` and `Col 2` is equal to `Group 5`

I tried to create a calculated field with the formula `=IF('Col 1' = "Type 1",  1, 0)` but it does not work.

I am trying to do this all in the pivot table, without using helper columns and what not. If I can't do it in this kind of pivot table, maybe a `QUERY` pivot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
={unique(B:B),arrayformula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(unique(B:B),query(A:E,"select B, count(C) where D='Type 1' and E='Group 5' group by B"),2,0),0))}
```

[image]

Comment: But I have multiple columns/criteria I want totals on for all of the months. Some months may have 0 for a particular column but another column won't. With that said, I did figure it out.